# jQuery and Knob animate issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-knob

I am trying to animate a number so that it rolls into the number when the page loads. I am using another library to display a dial (http://anthonyterrien.com/knob/). The issue I am having is that the number seems to be different every time I run it. It should be a consistent number ending on 19420. However sometimes it is lower and there doesn't seem to be any particular pattern.

My JS code looks like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('#dial').knob({
        min: '0',
        max: '25000',
        readOnly: true
    });

    $({
        value: 0
    }).animate({
        value: 19420 
    }, {
        duration: 950,
        easing: 'swing',
        step: function() {
            $('#dial').val(Math.round(this.value)).trigger('change');
        }
    });
});
```

The fiddle can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/ND5Sf/

What have I done wrong or is there anything I've missed out? If not, are these 2 libraries not compatible?

Comment: Probably because the duration of 950, the tick is too minor and I think miss something, if you set 3000 works well

Comment: Just tried it with 3000 and I still had the same problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is because you are using `step` function instead of `progress`.

Step:

> A function to be called for each animated property of each animated
>   element. This function provides an opportunity to modify the Tween
>   object to change the value of the property before it is set.

Progress:

> A function to be called after each step of the animation, only once
>   per animated element regardless of the number of animated properties.
>   (version added: 1.8)

Code:

```
$(function () {
    $('#dial').knob({
        min: '0',
        max: '25000',
        readOnly: true
    });

    $({
        value: 0
    }).animate({
        value: 19420
    }, {
        duration: 950,
        easing: 'swing',
        progress: function () {
            $('#dial').val(Math.round(this.value)).trigger('change');
        }
    });
});
```

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/JW2gP/

Comment: Just wondering, what if you have multiple dials on the page? http://jsfiddle.net/JW2gP/1/

Comment: Excellent thanks a lot this now works as expected. I guess that'll teach me to properly read the documentation

Comment: @Serberuss glad to help you, thanks for sharing the plugin very cool!